# Weird path bug in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I've seen this before, and this has always baffled me. Occasionally while manipulating an object in Illustrator, I end up with a path which seems like it's been broken — it shows a dramatic horizontal gap, as if there's a point far to the left or right of the actual path. When this shows up, it's almost always intermittent, disappearing on zoom. In the example I've created, shifting the object's position causes this gap to disappear and reappear.

**What's going on here?** Is this path corrupt? If so, is there any hope of fixing it? In this case I could recreate easily, but sometimes the object is something it took a long time to build.

Thank you! [image: 1]]

Comment: Never seen this. It may be a localized error due to your video card or something.

Comment: Yes, it looks like video card errors. When you export the image these articats should be gone

Comment: Some files seem to have it more consistently — I'll zoom in AND out, and it's repeatable. I feel as though I've seen this on other machines. But could be... In any case, turning on CPU preview, as @joshkrz suggested, changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that the GPU rendering in Illustrator can be a little buggy sometimes where artifacts can appear and shapes can clip for no apparent reason.

Try switching to a CPU preview in `View > Preview on CPU` to see if that fixes your issue.

[image: Preview on CPU]

Comment: Hey, that worked! I still feel like that reflects a bugginess in the file which might cause issues down the line. Right now working on logo files, and wouldn't want them to be corrupted! But maybe have to let that go...

Comment: Glad I could help. So far I haven't noticed any problems when these files go to production so I think you're safe, it's most likely how your video driver interprets the instructions from Illustrator to display your file on screen. Exporting / saving will render the file properly.